# PHP, FACEBOOK, PAGES, RSS: Help turning page feed into RSS (getting errors)

Tags: php, facebook

Ok, so following some instructions I found in another post here on StackOverflow, I have constructed a script to get a fan pages feed and turn it into an RSS2 feed. However, the script required a few changes and Im not the best programmer in the world, so I need a little help.

Im getting this error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in feed.php on line 48

Im not sure what the invalid argument is all about.

```
<?

// error reporting
echo '<pre>';
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// require your facebook php sdk
require('./facebook/facebook.php'); 

// include the feed generator feedwriter file                   
include("./feed/FeedWriter.php");                       


// config secret key and appid
$config = array(
'appId' =>  '',                             
'secret'=>  ''      
);

// Initialize
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

// Set Apps Permissions Request
$permission_scope = "";

   // get users access token
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    // get page post
    $feed_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/Ritualdubstep/feed?access_token='.$access_token;
    $feed_json = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $feed_data = json_decode($feed_json);

// create the feedwriter object 
$feed = new FeedWriter(RSS2);

$feed->setTitle('Ritual Dubstep'); // set your feed title
$feed->setLink('https://www.facebook.com/Ritualdubstep'); // set the url to the feed page you're generating

$feed->setChannelElement('updated', date(DATE_RSS , time()));
$feed->setChannelElement('author', array('name'=>'Ritual Dubstep SF')); // set the author name

// iterate through the facebook response to add items to the feed
foreach($feed_data['data'] as $entry){
    if(isset($entry["message"])){
        $item = $feed->createNewItem();
        $item->setTitle($entry["from"]["name"]);
        $item->setDate($entry["updated_time"]);
        $item->setDescription($entry["message"]);
        if(isset($entry["link"]))
            $item->setLink(htmlentities($entry["link"]));

        $feed->addItem($item);
        }
}

// generate feed
$feed->genarateFeed();
?>
```

Comment: is `$feed_data['data']` set?

Comment: try var_dump($feed_data['data']) just before the foreach and see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it means that the first argument in the `foreach` call (in this case `$feed_data['data']`) is not a valid array.

Make sure that `$feed_data['data']` exists (`isset($feed_data['data'])`) and that it is an array (`is_array($feed_data['data'])`) before running entering the `foreach` loop.

And - as [shapeshifter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082646/shapeshifter) mentioned in the comments - you might want to start troubleshooting by `var_dump($feed_data['data'])` right before you start the `foreach` loop to see what's being generated.

Comment: 2 things were wrong: 1 was that i wasnt using graph.facebook.com for the page url and 2 setting the second param of the json to true made the data into an array and everything is all good. except now the feed has an error about the xml document type needing to only be sent once.